# Firebase return a collection as an array

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to build an app using Firebase as the back end and need help with what seems like a simple problem. I want to return a list of nested data (I know I shouldn't be nesting data!) as an array. To try and solve this I have the following to give me a collection of the status for each record in the database:

```
    var ref = new Firebase("https://firebase_URL");
ref.orderByChild("Status").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    var articleID = snapshot.key();
    var articleData = snapshot.val();
    console.log(articleData.status.Status);
```

This gives me a collection of the Status but how do i combine these to console.log the list as an array?

Comment: Try apply `JSON.stringify`: `console.log(JSON.stringify(articleData.status.Status))`;

Comment: It seems JSON.stringify converts to a collection of strings rather than an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a array outside the scope of the firebase event, and on the event you push to it:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://firebase_URL");
var statusCollection = []; //Array outside the 'child_added' scope
ref.orderByChild("Status").on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    var articleID = snapshot.key();
    var articleData = snapshot.val();
    statusCollection.push(articleData.status.Status);
    //Console shows the full array collection
    console.log(statusCollection)
});
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Big help but is there any way of just logging the final  'statusCollection' rather than each iteration as each records status is added to the array?

Comment: You can log the status collection from anywhere outside the event, including from your browser console.